# Facebook stream Publish with attachment

Tags: c#, facebook, json

im trying to use the Test Console in this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) to post something on my wall with a swf attachment so im filling the following in the attachment:

```
{"media": [{
    "type": "flash", 
    "swfsrc": "http://www.alsacreations.fr/flashdir/dewplayer.swf?mp3=http://storage.musiclife.kz/2011-07/47449_3b012dcc460023b8be23f7af451e173f.mp3", 
    "imgsrc": "http://bikeweb.com/files/images/ride_it_forever_000113-1313.jpg", 
    "width": "80", 
    "height": "60",
    "expanded_width": "160", 
    "expanded_height": "120"
}]}
```

it posts and everything but when i click on the attachment it open a different window with the swf when i want it to be played inline just like youtube and several sites that i saw doing this, im not sure what im doing wrong ? any idea ?

also i would like to acommplish this with Facebook C# SDK, what do i need to change in the following code:

```
          _fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postparameters["message"] = "Test";
        postparameters["name"] = "This is a name";
        var result = _fbClient.Post("/me/feed", postparameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wat I used in PHP until Facebook introduced the bug with attachments on Timeline. They fixed it and this shoul be working again but honestly I haven't tried it.

```
$attachment =  array
  (
  'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken(),
  'message' => 'The message from the user - probably a submitted <textarea>',
  'name' => 'Name of the link',
  'caption' => 'Caption',
  'link' => 'the url to your application or whatever you wish',
  'description' => 'our description',
  'picture' => 'url of the image preview - required for flash',
  'type' => 'flash',
  'source' => 'the url to the flash file',
  );

   try {
     $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
   }
   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      error_log($e);
   }
```

}

Comment: thanks for posting Alexander Nenkov but this is kinda not related to my question i asked about the test console in facebook documentation page , and i asked about Facebook C# SDK you provided PHP Code...

Comment: So, you can't take the PHP array and switch it to C#?

Comment: i already did that and im using the TEST console , but when i click on play it open a new Windows with the flash instead of playing it online  that is what im asking about, please reread the question , the second part is asking about how to do it with "Facebook C# SDK"